# How do I disable hotkeys in Dojo StackContainer

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am using Dojo 1.2 to implement some functionality on my customer's webpage. One of the widgets I use is the `dijit.layout.TabContainer`, which inherits `StackContainer`. The `StackContainer` subscribes on keyboard events and creates a few hotkeys, like arrow left to move one tab to the left and so on.

Now to the question: I would like to disable this hotkey feature in my `TabContainer`. Is there a configuration option I can set (can't find any in the API) to achieve this, or will have to hack the Dojo code or perhaps create my own versions of `StackContainer` and `TabContainer` in order to rid myself of the hotkeys? I would of course prefer not to mess with the Dojo code.

Best regards / Fredrik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply override _onKeyPress with an empty body:

```
<div dojoType='dijit.layout.TabContainer'>
<script type='dojo/method' event='_onKeyPress'></script>
...
<div>
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: In recent versions of Dojo, the function to override is now `_onKeyDown`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just coding off the cuff here, and I didn't test it out at all.  I'm making this wikified, so post the correct source if there are any problems, please.

Use the following javascript within a file called `com/stackoverflow/KeyPresslessTabContainer.js`:

```
dojo.provide("com.stackoverflow. KeyPresslessTabContainer");

dojo.require("dijit.layout. TabContainer");

dojo.declare("com.stackoverflow.KeyPresslessTabContainer", dijit.layout. TabContainer, {
    _controllerWidget: "com.stackoverflow.KeyPresslessTabController"
});

dojo.declare("com.stackoverflow.KeyPresslessTabController", dijit.layout.TabController, {
  /*
   *  this is the important part.  The original code was:
   *  templateString: "<div wairole='tablist' dojoAttachEvent='onkeypress:onkeypress'></div>"
   *  In the template below, we remove the onkeypress listener,
   *  and thus key presses should be ignored.
   */
  templateString: "<div wairole='tablist'></div>"
});
```